# Add Remote option not shown in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

I am trying to set up a remote debugger with PyCharm on a Vagrant Machine. 
I am following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html) PyCharm tutorial. However, the Add Remote option is not available for me. Just Add local and Create VirtualEnv.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just as a guess: are you using the free community edition of PyCharm? Unfortunately remote interpreters and remote debugging are only supported by the professional edition. You might take a look into the [editions comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) on their website.

If you are using the pro version, we might have to dig a little deeper.

Comment: That was it. Remote interpreters are only supported in the professional edition. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what host system you are using but if you don't mind a bit of delay, I was able to use Xforwarding over ssh and I pulled pycharm down from my remote system. (ssh -X)  Pycharm detected it and gave a warning that it's updates are slowed but it worked.